# Ruby on Rails - Dividing a Class into multiple classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class

I have this app: Task Manager.

I have a `User`.

- A user can create one or more `Groups` -> then it becomes **admin** of the groups it created
- At the same time a user can be just a `Member` (a middle table between User and Group) of a Group created by another one.

So I have that User:

```
has_many :groups, foreign_key: :admin_id, dependent: :destroy
has_many :groups, through: :members
```

And now I want to ask to the Db:

- Give me the groups where user is admin
- Give me the groups where user is just a user

I can most likely create a SQL query for that but I thought there would be a more Rails way of doing things.

Is there a way to do this? I can only think of having User but at the same time dividing it into 2 different subclasses like UserAdmin and NormalUser. But I am not sure on how to do that or if it is even the right approach.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What about an intermediate model (you already seem to have a `member` table) with `user_id`, `group_id` and `role`. The latter can be `'member'` or `'admin'` to specify the user's role in that group. This way, you have a single table to query and you can easily have multiple admins per group (at least technically).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splitting your User class into multiple classes isn't the answer as you want users to be able to have different roles in different groups. Rather there are few different solutions.

### 1. Add a foreign key column

If you want to have a specific one to many assocation between a user and a group you can add a separate assocation:

```
class AddCreatorToGroups < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]                                                                   
  def change
    # note that you'll have to worry about filling this 
    # column if you have existing data                                                                                                                
    add_reference :groups, :founder, null: false, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }                                                      
  end                                                                                                                   
end 

class Group
  # ...
  belongs_to :founder, 
    class_name: 'User',
    inverse_of: :groups_as_founder
end

class User
  # ...
  has_many :groups_as_founder,
    class_name: 'Group',
    foreign_key: :founder_id,
    inverse_of: :founder
end
```

This is a good idea if you need to be able to eager load the group and just that user very efficiently. This would be set when creating the group:

```
def create
  @group = Group.new(group_params) do |group|
    group.founder = current_user
  end
  # ...
end
```

This can be combined with the other options. It won't solve the case where you want to assign multiple admins to a group.

### 2. Add the roles to the memberships

```ruby
class AddCreatorToGroups < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]                                                                   
  def change                                                                                                                
    add_columns :memberships, :role, :integer, default: 0
  end                                                                                                                   
end
```

```ruby
class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :member, class_name: 'User'
  enum :role, {
     normal: 0,
     admin: 1
  }
end
```

```ruby
class Group < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :normal_memberships,
     class_name: 'Membership',
     -> { Membership.normal }
   has_many :admin_memberships,
     class_name: 'Membership',
     -> { Membership.admin }

  has_many :normal_members,
    class_name: 'User',
    through: :normal_memberships

  has_many :admin_members,
    class_name: 'User',
    through: :admin_memberships
end
```

```ruby
class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :normal_memberships,
     class_name: 'Membership',
     -> { Membership.normal }
   has_many :admin_memberships,
     class_name: 'Membership',
     -> { Membership.admin }

  has_many :groups_as_normal_member,
    class_name: 'Group',
    through: :normal_memberships

  has_many :groups_as_admin_member,
    class_name: 'Group',
    through: :admin_memberships
end
```

This is a greatly simpliefied example where the available roles are defined through an enum on the memberships table. A more complex example could have the role defined as `role_id` pointing to a separate table.

This repition can be avoided somewhat by looping across `Membership.roles.key`.

One thing to consider is that it places a lot of responsibities into the Membership class.

### 3. A separate role system.

An additional alternative would be to use a separate system such as Rolify and a completely different set of tables to store the roles in a group. There are plenty of tutorials on how to use Rolify or build a role based access system from scratch if you search a bit.

Comment: Note that I used `membership` and not `member` intentionally.

Comment: Thank you!! When you say it membership belongs to member I am having it difficult to understand. 
My current structure is User -> Member <- Group since the relationship between User and Group is: many-to-many. Why would then Membership belong to Member and Group and not User and Group? Thank you for the amazing response btw!

Comment: This isn't an additional table. What you're calling Member should be named Membership. In English you can be a *member* of a group but that's a adverb - the noun is *membership* unless you're talking about the person. For example you would have a *membership card* and thats really what this table represents.

Comment: This gives naming that actually makes sense to English speakers - a User `has_many :memberships`. And a group `has_many :members, through: :memberships, class_name: 'User'`.